# Get all the posts where meta field with multiple choice has several values checked

Tags: custom-field, advanced-custom-fields, post-meta

I apologize beforehand for any confusion, I'm just 2 days with WP.

So, I use [Advanced Custom Fields](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) to add formatable custom fields to posts of partucular type.
One of fields is checkboxes with multiple choice with name `spec`.
Now I want to get all posts where `spec` has one or more values checked.

For example: 
choices for this field are {"choice1","choice2",choice3","choice4","choice5"}
In some post I selected "choice2" and "choice3" and saved these posts.

if I print `spec` in loop

```
print_r( get_post_meta($post->ID,'spec',true));
```

it can looks like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => choice2
    [1] => choice3
)
```

Now I want to get all posts where "choice2" or "choice3" are selected (or may be only `choice2` or only `choice3`):

```
query_posts(
    array(
        'cat' => 6,
        'posts_per_page'=>-1,
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'spec'
                'value' => array('choice2','choice3'),
                'compare' => 'IN'
            )
        )
    )
);
```

But that not works. As I understand the real condition will be `WHERE spec IN 'choice2'`, where choice is array. But I need opposite condition - something like `in_array('choice2',spec) || in_array('choice3',spec)`. May be there is some `HAS` value for `compare`?

So my question - how can I get all the posts where meta field with multiple choice has several values checked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you try to call like this:

```
$args = array(
  'post_type'  => 'product',
  'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
        'key'     => 'spec',
        'value'   => 'choice2',
        'compare' => 'LIKE',
    ),
    array(
        'key'     => 'spec',
        'value'   => 'choice3',
        'compare' => 'LIKE',
    ),
  ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

example taken straigh from the [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters)

Comment: Thanks, @peteroak, that works! Probably I was baffled by the fact that `LIKE` is applies more to strings than to arrays.

Comment: glad i could help! :D

Comment: Now I noticed that it work not as I expected. for example if I have choices `{"aa","bb","aacc"}` and `aa` is criteria for searching so it returns also posts where only `aacc` was selected. In other words it works like a real `LIKE` but I need it works like `in_array`

Comment: Ok, after a bit of research I've found that WP loop does not get meta data in account while SQL query. It can be easy shown by `echo $GLOBALS['wp_query']->request`. As I understand WP receives all the query records without meta filtering (OMG!) and apply this filter in loop itself for each record. So I removed all meta filter from `query_posts` to do that by myself, in code with `in_array`.

Comment: nice insight. in the case above, you could use %aa% to get xxaabb. you should write your own answer too below ;)